# Sending a message to game scene

Tags: ios, swift

I have this function in my SimonButton.swift file

```
func deactivate(){
    //Deactivates the button
    self.active = false
    self.alpha = 0.5
    self.timeActivated = nil
    self.timeActive = nil
    buttonSoundPlayer.stop()
}
```

And at the end of it I want the function to call a certain GameScene function.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Where there's a will, there's a way. But you'll have to give us more info. What is `self`—a `UIButton`, an `SKNode`, something else?

Comment: If you want to access a certain class from anywhere, then you are probably looking at implementing the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (which we really can't, because you haven't provided enough information) you've created `SimonButton.swift` and instantiated it from your `GameScene.swift`, you can pass a reference to your `SKScene` to the `SimonButton`. 
Here is a fake SpriteKit Swiftstub situation:
http://swiftstub.com/242703800

```
public class GameScene:SKScene {

    var button:SimonButton!

    func didMoveToView(view:SKView) {
        button = SimonButton(scene: self)
    }
}

public class SimonButton {
    var main:SKScene!
    init(scene:SKScene) {
        main = scene
    }

    func draw() {
        print(main)
    }
}
```